# error: can't exec 'codesign' after upgrade to Xcode 5.0

Tags: path, osx-mountain-lion, upgrade, xcode5, codesign

I got 
error: can't exec 'codesign' (No such file or directory) after I upgrade to Xcode 5.0.
when I try to run the app on the real device.

My codesign file is under /usr/bin.

but somehow, xcode could not locate it.

Comment: Yes, I did install the command after the upgrade.

Comment: go to Preferences -> Locations - check Command Line tools is set to the latest version (5A1412)

Comment: Thanks LearnCocos2D.  I found out the problem, my /etc/launchd.conf had some error.  I fix it.  Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors in my /etc/launchd.conf file.  I correct the issue in launchd.conf file.  and I restarted my computer, everything works fine.

My launchd.conf looks like this now.

```
setenv PATH /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/emmychen/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/emmychen/bin
```